# From RDD pipeline to DF Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This question appeared well trodden as I started looking for help, but I haven't found a solution yet. In fact, you might find a few you see as possible duplicates, but I think I have tried them all in the last few hours. From what I understand, sqlContext is going to do the trick here, but I am open to any answer that works. I'm using Spark 2.1

I am starting with an id list that I am pulling down from mongodb.
Sample output:

```
[u'182028', u'161936', u'12333', u'120677']
'rated_game_ids_lst type:' <type 'list'>
```

I then move on to try creating an RDD that I want to turn into a DF:

```
user_unrated_games = ugr_rdd.filter(lambda x: x[1] not in rated_game_ids_lst).map(lambda x: (19, x[1], x[2]))
```

Sample output:

```
'user_unrated_games:' [(19, u'174430', 3.4), (19, u'169786', 3.4)]
'user_unrated_games type:' <class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'>
```

and a sample of the urg_rdd I use above (first row):

```
'ugr_rdd:'[Row(user_id=5, game_id=u'182028', rating=9.15)]
'ugr_rdd_type:' pyspark.rdd.RDD
```

I then try this:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(user_unrated_games, ['user_id', 'game_id', 'rating'])
```

That method fails so I tried this:

```
user_unrated_games = ugr_rdd.filter(lambda x: x[1] not in rated_game_ids_lst).map(lambda x: Row(user_id=19, game_id=x[1], rating= x[2]))
```

Sample output:

```
('user_unrated_games type:', <class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'>)
('user_unrated_games:', [Row(game_id=u'174430', rating=3.4, user_id=19), Row(game_id=u'169786', rating=3.4, user_id=19)])
```

and then this:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(user_unrated_games)
```

Both of these attempts give this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':"
```

From there, I started trying combinations of changing the types of "user_id", etc., tried passing the RDD as is, tried to convert my pipeline to an RDD...frankly I tried a lot of things, but the two above look the closest to what seem to work for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you need to specify the schema including data types when calling the `createDataFrame` method.  Something like this should do the trick:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

rdd = sc.parallelize([(19, 174430, 3.4), (19, 169786, 3.4)])

schema = StructType( [
    StructField('user_id', IntegerType()),
    StructField('game_id', IntegerType()),
    StructField('rating', FloatType())
    ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

df.show()
```

NOTE:  I've tested this using spark 2.1.0.  In this case `spark` is a `SparkSession` object.

Comment: note an important point here: the variable types in the rdd you are converting need to match the schema you are passing to createDataFrame